# Pass parameters from a script that are passed by keyboard

Tags: bash, shell

I need to write a shell script that help me to automatically connect to vpn after executing this script

A vpnc program require following inputs

```
root@xmpp3:/home/test/Desktop/ScriptTovpnc# vpnc
Enter IPSec gateway address: 
Enter IPSec ID for : 
Enter IPSec secret for @: 
Enter username for : 
Enter password for @: 
vpnc: unknown host `'
```

I am unable to write script,how i will pass all these parameters in that script.

Comment: If `vpnc` won't take them as command line arguments, then you're likely to need `expect` or a workalike to drive the data to the program while leaving you able to continue typing after a successful connection.

Comment: AFAIK, `vpnc` also has a config file (`/etc/vpnc.conf` &/OR `/etc/vpnc/default.conf`), where you can store everything in plain text. If any entry (typically, password) is omitted, then you would be prompted for it.

Answer (score 2):

[anishsane's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652186/pass-parameters-from-a-script-that-are-passed-by-keyboard#comment27469271_18652186) is right. Use a config file!

But just in case here is `expect` script that automates the entering of your data:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn vpnc

expect "Enter IPSec gateway address;"
send "yourdata\r";

expect "Enter IPSec ID for"
send "yourdata\r";

expect "Enter IPSec secret for"
send "yourdata\r";

expect "Enter username for"
send "yourdata\r";

expect "Enter password for"
send "yourdata\r";
```

And you can make it smaller if you pass most of your data as command line arguments as [suggested by Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652186/pass-parameters-from-a-script-that-are-passed-by-keyboard#comment27465263_18652186):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn vpnc --gateway yourgateway --id yourid --username yourusername

expect "Enter IPSec secret for"
send "yourdata\r";

expect "Enter password for"
send "yourdata\r";
```

But as already mentioned, it is not the way to go. Use a config file instead.

Comment: Your suggested script prompt me for details...I just need to execute my script and vpn should be connected, i didn't want details to be prompted, they should be passed in script.

Comment: @AbdulManaf what do you mean by ``promt me for details`` ? What kind of details does it want? Everything should be passed by ``expect``. What output do you get?

Comment: It means i have to pass Gateway Add,Id ,username etc..,while i execute this script.I want these details to stored in some variables in script and i should only need to call the script.

Comment: @AbdulManaf That's how it works. Just replace ``yourdata`` with any data you want.

Comment: I see, It is very slow on execution ? And i also have hit Return Key why this ?

Comment: @AbdulManaf It shouldn't be slow. Oh! Just remove ``interact`` line to fix return key issue.